# Update, insert from one table to other table without a primary key (or combination of mutliple fields)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As title says, I want to transfer data from one table to another. With no primary keys. This should be something I will be able to execute daily, so a stored procedure is a must.

Now, I have tried an EXCEPT statement. But I'm not able to update/insert the data. I get the columns that are different between the two tables, but I'm clueless whether this should be an update or an insert...
I also want to use the MERGE statement if possible. 
Another point is that the target table will have an identity(1, 1) (ID) that is not changing. The source table does not.

I can't wrap my head around the problem I'm facing, feel free to give me the direction to go too or ask any question.

Comment: please explain with some examples and show expected output

Comment: So long as there is *something* to identify the correct rows to update/insert/ignore this should be a trivial task, but until you provide the additional contextual information there is very little help we can provide.

Comment: I have orders, wich is an one line order with an 'order-nr' (PK). In another table i have the order details. The problem here is that there is nothing of sorts like 'an order line id' primary key. Or a combination of multiple fields that make it unique. I can always combine all lines to a combined primary key but even then there might be a possibility for duplicate lines....